# JavaScript num.toFixed() method

Tags: javascript, tofixed

I have question regarding JavaScript toFixed().
I am facing some difference in rounding,

```js
let num1=1.635;
let num2=10.635;

console.log(num1.toFixed(2)); // I am getting the output as 1.64 which is correct.
console.log(num2.toFixed(2)); // but now I am getting 10.63 instead of 10.64.
```

can anyone explain about this behavior of the above code and suggest how to overcome this?

Comment: floating point is broken - not really, but there's a lot of things like this ... `0.1 + 0.2` for example

Comment: TL;DR: if you're using floats, you simply cannot expect any one particular number as "correct" answer.

Comment: If you check `10.635.toFixed(20)`, you will find it is `10.63499999999999978684`, which is closer to `10.63` than to `10.64`. On the other hand, `1.635.toFixed(20)` shows `1.63500000000000000888`, which is closer to `1.64` than to `1.63`.